# vuejs with multiple pages

Tags: vue.js, vue-cli

I would like to create a project that builds multiple pages with different style files and js files.
for example variant1 has variant1.css and each html is consist of different combination of components.

1. Is it correct to set vue cli config files for that?
   I was thinking of using router vue but then it's not the concept I wanted because it's creating the whole css as one file.

output should be like this

```
dist
|-- css
|   |-- chunk-vendors.1019b600.css
|   |-- customer
|   |   |-- variant1.fb147df7.css
|   |   |-- variant2.fb147df7.css
|   |   |-- variant3.fb147df7.css
|   |-- index.5745861f.css
|-- customer
|   |-- variant1.html
|   |-- variant2.html
|   |-- variant3.html
|-- index.html
|-- js
|   |-- chunk-vendors.4ebf6fb0.js
|   |-- chunk-vendors.4ebf6fb0.js.map
|   |-- customer
|   |   |-- variant1.00a1ecbf.js
|   |   |-- variant2.6f23ba31.js
|   |   |-- variant3.e4f7f212.js
|   |-- index.63fb9967.js
|   |-- index.63fb9967.js.map
```

vue.config.js file :

```
'use strict'
const titles = require('./title.js')
const glob = require('glob')
const pages = {}
const path = require('path')

glob.sync('./src/pages/**/app.js').forEach((path) => {
  const chunk = path.split('./src/pages/')[1].split('/app.js')[0]
  pages[chunk] = {
    entry: path,
    template: 'public/index.html',
    title: titles[chunk],
    chunks: ['chunk-vendors', 'chunk-common', chunk],
  }
})
module.exports = {
  outputDir: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist/apps'),
  publicPath: '/dist/apps/',
  pages,
  chainWebpack: (config) => config.plugins.delete('named-chunks'),
}
```

2. I made output dir to be located in a sub directory. I know that I can use './' for the public path and put in any sub directory in apache folder.
   but then the sub-pages can't find bundled files.

   module.exports = {
   publicPath: './',
   pages,
   chainWebpack: (config) => config.plugins.delete('named-chunks'),
   }

how can I make this work?

in other words,

http://dd.localhost.com/dist/customer/variant1.html is trying to find
http://dd.localhost.com/dist/customer/css/customer/variant1.fb147df7.css

instead of below correct path

http://dd.localhost.com/dist/css/customer/variant1.fb147df7.css

Comment: Is it important that you have multiple html pages? You can simply use `scoped css` in your different components (not the main one!) and chosse between `vue-router` or think about [dynamic components](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/component-basics.html#dynamic-components) for navigation. The output will be only one index.html...

Comment: yes. I need to make different pages per customers (that serves same componenent and data structure) but only with different styles and different layouts. is vue-router applicable in this case as well?

Comment: with vue-router you can achieve something like that `domain.com/customer/Variant1`, `domain.com/customer/Variant2`, ... to switch layouts and styles you could [pass props](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/passing-props.html) to the single component.